# Is Google Analytic's enhanced link attribution for in-page analysis outdated? What are the alternatives?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I would like to extend the in-page analysis with Google Analytics enhanced link attribution. When following the link to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6047802 from the Google Analytics property settings page, it says that "This extension will no longer receive updates." (meaning the Chrome extension).

Does this mean that the entire Google Analytic's enhanced link attribution feature is deprecated and should not be used anymore? At https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-link-attribution I cannot find any information like this.

If the feature is deprecated, what should be used instead? If only the Google Chrome browser extension is outdated, what is then the way to investigate the measured data?